# C# - Null conversion fails

Tags: c#, regex

```
string valueStr = " "; //"(123)-456-7890" or null or " " or "" or string.Empty or "abcdef"
int valueInt;

if (valueStr.Trim() != null || valueStr.Trim() != string.Empty || valueStr.Trim() != "")
{
    //Perform regex routine to convert valueStr to valueInt and get only digits
}
else
{
    valueInt = null;
}
```

I will be inserting data into SQL Db. I am trying to clean a alpha-numeric column {(n)varchar} into just numeric {int}.

However, the above logic gives me error for "valueInt = null;" part.

```
Error = "Cannot convert null to int because it is a non-nullable value type"
```

How can I make sure that the code will perform regular expression functionality for only rows that has some data and give out null if there is no data?

Thank you

Update:

```
string valueStr = " "; //"(123)-456-7890" or null or string.Empty or " " or "abcdef"
int? valueInt;

    if (valueStr != null && valueStr.Trim() != "")
    {
        string pattern = string.Empty;
        pattern = "[^0-9]";
        Regex r = null;
        r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
        try
        {
             valueInt = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(valueStr, pattern, string.Empty));
        }
        catch
        {
             valueInt = null;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(valueInt);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        valueInt = null;
        Console.WriteLine(valueInt);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Make it nullable or equal to some value like `-1`.

Comment: The code might just be for demonstration, but just in case it's worth noting that, in your third line, if `valueStr` is null you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.  There doesn't seem to be any way `.Trim()` can return null otherwise, so you might want to remove the `.Trim()` from the first part of the condition.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin, If I use " " for valueStr, the code inside If condition still executes...shouldn't it NOT execute with above if condition (minus .Trim() for the first part)?

Comment: I think you want to `&&` your conditions instead of `||`.  Also, `string.Empty` is `""`, so your last two conditions are identical.

Comment: ahh...I feel stupid and I should feel bad. :( Know a way to give null when there is only non-int values in valueStr (i.e. "abc")..this code fails for that case.

Comment: I think I got it working, how does it look?

Comment: Good.  You could combine the declaration and initialization lines - there's no benefit to initializing to string.Empty or null first.  There's also no harm but consistency is nice.  Strictly speaking it's better not to ignore exceptions without logging them, but it might not matter for your case.

Comment: Yeah, I will update those. As for exception, this is not a C# app, it will be used in an ETL app so don't need any logging. Just curious, since I am using try/catch, do I need if/else? I tried removing if/else and just kept the code within if loop and it seems to work OK. any benefits? I have 10K rows coming through so, would it affect any performance or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `valueInt` variable like this:

```
int? valueInt;
```

Then you can assign it to null.For more information about `Nullable types` see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign null to an `int`. You can, however, assign null to a `Nullable<int>` or `int?`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the variable a nullable int if you wish to assign null to it:

```
int? valueInt;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Look into using String.IsNullOrEmpty, it is a useful shortcut.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx
2. Is the database column for valueInt nullable?
3. You cannot set an integer to Null.  Look into Nullable types or try setting a distinct default value such as 0 or -1.

Comment: Source column = string that would have either null, or blank spaces, or apha-numaric values. The destination column is of int datatype and is nullable. My goal is to get only the digits out of w/e is passed and if there is no digits, assign it (int)null.

Comment: Check out String.IsNullOrEmpty to fix the string null reference error EvilPengiun brought up.  I don't know how you are inserting the values into sql, but you can use a nullable type or have a switch on the insert.  I think declared integers have a base value of 0, so you can check for 0 and switch with Null.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of integers, you may like to assign to some arbitrary number that can be tested with the same equality operator, `==`, as if you were to assign to `null`.
Something like this:

```
// fail case
valueInt = -1;
```

The value `-1` is not the same as `null`, but can be tested against in a later `if` condition to see if the "fail case" occurred in your test case.
Then you can do something like this later:

```
if (valueInt == -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value not captured correctly. Value must be a number.");
}
```

Comment: with valueStr = " ", my code inside the if condition executes, does this have anything to do with it? I am still a bit confused about this arbitrary -1 value..going to read again..one word at a time.

Comment: I was assuming that `valueStr = " "` was just test data. You're sanitizing phone numbers correct? Are you using a regex to strip out `(, ), -` or are you using just a simple replace?

Comment: Updated the OP. :) and yes, I am sanitizing the phone numbers.

Comment: Got it working with updated code...except for when valueStr has no digits...it fails. i.e. "abc"